# D3.js path styles strokeDasharray

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

an array with objects arrives

```
let data = [{
  id: 1,
  times: [7619846500000, 7619860000000,7619873600000,7619887200000],
  values: [14.725565836745528, 14.725565836745529, 14.72556583674553],
  dashtime:[7619873600000]
},{
    id: 2,
    times: [7619846400000, 7619850000000,7619853600000,7619857200000,7619860800000],
    values: [14.725565836745528, 14.725565836745529, 14.72556583674553,14.72556583674553],
    dashtime:[7619853600000]
  }];
```

using the dAttributeGenerator function, the result is converted to d and passed to Path

```
const attributes = data.map((signal, signalIndex) => {
const X = signal?.times;
const Y = signal?.values;
const I = d3.range(X?.length);

const dAttributeGenerator = d3
  .line()
  .x((i) => xScale(X[i]))
  .y((i) => (yAxisCount !== 1 ? yScales[0](Y[i]) : yScales[0](Y[i])));
 
  const d = dAttributeGenerator(I)
  return d})

  <Path
    d={d}
    fill={"none"}
    stroke={'blue'}
    strokeDasharray={"3"}
    style={{ transition: hasTransition ? "all 0.7s" : "" }}
   />
```

the task is that if the point by timestamp is before the value of dashtime, then it is drawn with strokeDasharray={"0"}, if the point is equal to dashtime or greater, then strokeDasharray={"3"}

expected result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EVDy.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You will need two separate paths. One path cannot have two `stroke-dasharray`s. (You *could* have a `stroke-dasharray` specific to the lengths of the paths in question, something like `500 3 3 3 3 3 3...`, but please don't do this.)